# Compare the two arrays and replace/merge the values for id present in the other array (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two arrays, and I want to be able to compare the two and replace the object values for id present in the info array with the details array and populate the rest as it is.  I haven't found anything like this. What would be the best way to return similarities?

```
const details = [{
    id: "id1",
    description: "new description-1"
  },
  {
    id: "id3",
    linkUrl: "new link-1"
  }
]

const info = [{
    id: "id1",
    description: "old description-1",
    linkUrl: "#id1link-1",
    image: "#imageUrl-1"
  },
  {
    id: "id2",
    description: "description-2",
    linkUrl: "#id1link-2",
    image: "#imageUrl-2"
  },
  {
    id: "id3",
    description: "description-3",
    linkUrl: "#old link-2",
    image: "#imageUrl-2"
  }
]

const result = [{
    id: "id1",
    description: "new description-1",
    linkUrl: "#id1link-1",
    image: "#imageUrl-1"
  },
  {
    id: "id2",
    description: "description-2",
    linkUrl: "#id1link-2",
    image: "#imageUrl-2"
  },
  {
    id: "id3",
    description: "description-3",
    linkUrl: "#new link-2",
    image: "#imageUrl-2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For larger amounts of data, it is best to first create a map for the details data, so that retrieving an id can happen in constant time:

```js
const details = [{id:"id1",description: "new description-1"},{id: "id3",linkUrl: "new link-1"}];
const info = [{id: "id1",description: "old description-1",linkUrl: "#id1link-1",image: "#imageUrl-1"},{id: "id2",description: "description-2",linkUrl: "#id1link-2",image: "#imageUrl-2"},{id: "id3",description: "description-3",linkUrl: "#old link-2",image: "#imageUrl-2"}];

const map = new Map(details.map(({id, ...rest}) => [id, rest]));
const result = info.map(o => ({...o, ...map.get(o.id)}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Trincot, I had another doubt regarding passing the child props to the parent. component. Posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69217494/11308487. Could you please help me with it? (I, yet do not have a reputation of 15, building points, will upvote as soon as I have just enough points to upvote) Thank you :)

Comment: Done, thank you for sharing the information on marking :)

Answer (score 2):

Using map, Find and Destructuring assignment.

```
const result = info.map(item => {
    const new_info = details.find(detail => detail.id === item.id);

    return {
        ...item,
        ...new_info,
    };
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Would it be possible to use reduce instead of a map and find?

Comment: A reduce is not for what you are after. Reduce is for summing up values, You could use it that way however thats what map is for.

Comment: Understood. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Uppercase if to lower case, No need for an else after a return if e.g. `if (details) { return details; } else { return ... };` just `if (details) { return ...; } return ...` since the block statement has been returned there is no way to get there unless false. regarding using the same var names this can work but I personally would not.

Comment: Hi Michael, I had another question, if you have an idea could you help me, posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217494/react-js-i-want-title-prop-from-title-component-into-list-component-for-aria-la